How to do DOF & motion blur using 1 image & depth?
Is there any way to do DOF & motion blur based on just 1 image & its depth image on a mobile platform?

I don't believe you'll be able to create a motion blur effect without information about the velocity of various parts of the image.

thanks! so do i:P it seems that it's just able to use specific filter to simulate it.

What uses a specific filter to simulate it?

the 1 image with its depth image
